# How to set up MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, installation

How do I set up this query?
I have awards in a table.
For example, a trophy may be award_id 1 in the award table.  A ribbon may be award_id 2 in the award table.
I then have another table, award_user, where it has the award_id and the userid of the user.  So, if I wanna give the user the award_id 1, and their userid is 25, it will be in the award_user table as award_id 1 and userid 25 (which means they have that award).  I want to select all of the awards the user has based off of their userid.

Here is the thing, though.  The awards are in the award table, but the actual user information about the awards are in the award table.  So, I will have to select from two different places, I guess.

Here is what I have so far..

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from award WHERE award_id = (SELECT award_id FROM award_user WHERE userid = $userid)");

Not sure if this will work or not.

Basically, it has to select the awards from the award table with the award_id's that the userid has.  $userid is a valid variable, it is their userid.

Thanks!

Comment: you just (likely) need a simple join here. Show both your table structures and someone can show you how to join based on table shared column relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of expressing the query should work, with one minor tweak.  You need to change the `=` to `in`, because there can be more than one aware

```
SELECT *
from award a
WHERE a.award_id in (SELECT au.award_id FROM award_user au WHERE au.userid = $userid)
```

More typically, this would be expressed as a join:

```
select a.*
from award a join
     award_user au
     on a.award_id = au.award_id
where au.userid = $userid;
```

The `join` form is often more efficient as well.

Comment: I am trying the first query using in.  Here is how I modified it.  SELECT * from award, award_user WHERE award_id in (SELECT award_id FROM award_user WHERE userid = $userid)    However,  testing it out replacing $userid with the number 1 in phpMyAdmin, I get #1052 - Column 'award_id' in IN/ALL/ANY subquery is ambiguous

Comment: Your from clause has `from award, award_user`.  This is generated a cross product and causing the problem.  The ambiguity is the `award_id in` part of the statement.

Comment: SELECT * from award WHERE award_id in (SELECT award_id FROM award_user WHERE userid = $userid)  This works.  However, I need to select a column called "issue_id" from the 'award_user' table, which is why I was trying to SELECT * from both of those tables.

Comment: @alfredo . . . Then use the second query and just add `au.issue_id` to the `select` clause.  You cannot pull additional columns from tables referenced in the `where` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this.  I have only worked with basic queries.  I tried the second query, replacing $userid with 1, and I get an error.  #1054 - Unknown column 'au.userid' in 'where clause'  Query:    select a.*
from award a join
     award_user aw
     on a.award_id = au.award_id
where au.userid = 1

Comment: @alfredo . . .There was a type (`aw` instead of `au` as the table alias).

Comment: Wow, thanks!  Hopefully this works in my script.  The query works fine.  select a.*, issue_id
from award a join
     award_user aw
     on a.award_id = aw.award_id
where aw.userid = 1

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html):

```
SELECT awards.* FROM awards
  JOIN award_user USING (award_id)
WHERE userid = :userid
```

By the way, learning [how joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is the one thing you *really* need to do in order to make proper use of SQL.  They're what relational databases are all about.  If you're using an SQL database but not using joins, it's a bit like, say, having a fancy new computer but only using it to read and write text in Notepad.